# How to parse json array in retrofit with no parameter name?

Tags: java, android, json

I have a json array of PDF files. What i need is to parse the pdf file via indexes, as there are no parameter name, just a value as PDF file. You can see my PDF file:

```
 @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    // response
                    Gson gson = new Gson() ;
                    MagazineResponseModel bookResponseModel;
                    bookResponseModel = gson.fromJson(response.toString(),MagazineResponseModel.class);
                    listGridViewBooks.addAll(bookResponseModel.getBooks());
                    mGridView.setAdapter(new MagazineGridViewAdapter(getActivity(),
                            R.layout.custom_books_view, listGridViewBooks));

                }
```

Here is the example JSON response, i want to parse the first item of "file" array. Does any body have an idea? Let me know if you need more explanation.

```
{"file": [
  "file1.pdf",
  "file2.pdf"
]  }
```

Comment: *what* problem?

Comment: @luk2302, I want to parse the array but not able to get the pdf file from 0 INDEX

Comment: wouldnt be the right way to do it..... did you write up the json?

Comment: @DroiDev, Please review question again

Comment: @kashifahmad can you post the actual JSON... then I can write the script to parse it. make it easier for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
{
  "file": [
      "file1.pdf",
      "file2.pdf"
    ]  
}
```

This would be the best way to get the json object.

Then, you can do this....

```
    JSONObject object = new JSONObject(jsonData);
    
    System.out.println(object);
    
    JSONArray file = object.getJSONArray("file");
    System.out.println(file);
    
    for (int i = 0; i < file.length(); i++) {
        System.out.println(file.get(i));
    }
```

It would print this.

> {"file":["file1.pdf","file2.pdf"]}
>
> ["file1.pdf","file2.pdf"]
>
> file1.pdf
>
> file2.pdf

Answer (score 1):

```
 JSONArray fileArray = bookObject.getJSONArray("file");
 for (int j = 0; j<fileArray.length(); j++){
 JSONArray nestedFileArray = fileArray.getJSONArray(j);                                       
 YOUR_MODEL.setFile(nestedFileArray.getString(YOUR_FILE_POSITION));}
```

I re-write the @droiDev answer for better results

Comment: "better" results. cmon now.